# Is it possible to add a dependency file from another module in my module.info?

Tags: 7, .info

In the docs:

> files (Optional)
>       Drupal supports a dynamic-loading code registry. To support it, all modules must declare any code files containing class or interface
>   declarations in the .info file, like so:
>
> ```
> name = Really Neat Widget
> ...
> files[] = tests/example.test
> ```
>
> When a module is enabled, Drupal will rescan all declared files and index all the classes and interfaces that it finds. Classes will be loaded automatically by PHP when they are first accessed.

But, it is posible to add a file fomr another module?

For example:

files[]: myothermodule/includes/file.inc

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: I guessing that i have to use module_load_include whereever needed?

Comment: You got it! It's more lightweight that way anyways.

Comment: I believe that you should also add the module as a dependency in your module's .info file or check if module_exists before accessing the file/function/class.